# Insert a list of python dictionary to sql server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have a list of dictionaries which I am trying to insert into a sql table using pyodbc

```
agent_list = [{'agent_str': 'GN1RLWFH011-2020-04-13-12-56-30-899936.txt', 'name_test': 'GN1RLWFH011', 'timestamp': '2020-04-13-12-56-30'}, {'agent_str': 'GN1RLWFH011-2020-04-13-13-02-36-611697.txt', 'name_test': 'GN1RLWFH011', 'timestamp': '2020-04-13-13-02-36'}]
```

What I have tried

```
crsr=conn.cursor()
crsr.executemany("""
INSERT INTO 
    framework.dbo.VS_Suspects
    (agent_str, name_test, timestamp)
VALUES
    (%(agent_str)s, %(name_test)s, %(timestamp)s)
""", agents_list)
```

But keep getting the following errors:

```
'Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000'
```

Any help on inserting a list of dictionaries to the SQL table is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could use SQLAlchemy to do that.

Comment: I am using pyodbc but having problem with insert statement